# How to find the records that do not have a specific value on a different column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example:

My Table:

| Accountid | Subid | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 11 | A |
| 001 | 12 | B |
| 002 | 13 | A |
| 002 | 14 | C |
| 003 | 15 | B |
| 003 | 16 | C |

How can I find all the Accountid that do not have any record with Type = A.

So the result should be:

| Accountid | Subid | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 003 | 15 | B |
| 003 | 16 | C |

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want the rows with an Accountid not having an A row?

Comment: That's correct! If there are a record with the same Account id  and have the type = A, then I don't want that Account id

Comment: You really should post what you have attempted.   And what your output / errors are and what the expected result should be.   Expecting someone to write a query for you isn't what this board is designed for.  It's for discussing questions that have **specific** problems with code.

Comment: [Try to Solve The Problem First](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) 
-- 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
-- 
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You are right, I should also post what I have attempted. Will do next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
  check_type AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(
      CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY account_id
    )
      AS account_has_type_a
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  check_type
WHERE
  account_has_type_a = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.Accountid, t.Subid,t.Type
from your_table as t
where not exists
(
  select 1 from your_table as x
   where t.Accountid=x.Accountid and x.type='A'
)
```

please try something like this

Comment: Beat me by one second :)